# Who really said these words that Todo quotes in his day-dream?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

During the Goodwill Event, when Todo Aoi finds out Itadori Yuji's taste in women, he goes into an intense day-dream where he and Itadori are high-school classmates. In his day-dream, Todo declares his intention to confess to Takada-chan, who is also a student in the same school in his fantasy, and he has the following conversation with Itadori:

> **Todo:** Why are you sure that I would be dumped?
> **Itadori:** On the other hand, why do you think she would agree?
> **Todo:** Anne Sullivan once said this to Helen Keller. "How can a fool think about losing before he does it?"
> **Itadori:** That's what Inoki said.

I have heard of [Anne Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Sullivan) and [Helen Keller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Keller), but who might be Inoki? My best guess is that it refers to the wrestler [Antonio Inoki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Inoki), but I am unable to confirm or deny it. In case it is an actual quote said by a real person named Inoki, could someone please provide a source for it?

Furthermore, as Todo comes out of his day-dream, he recites another quote (at least, the subtitles that I have seen place these words within double quotes):

> At home, we are invincible…

Perhaps this is also a real quote, said by the same Inoki encountered earlier? Any help in tracking down these quotes would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Todo was quoting Antonio Inoki... and song lyrics.**

The quote "*How can a fool think about losing before he does it?*" was a parody of Antonio Inoki's reply in a pre-match interview at *'90 New Japan Pro-Wrestling Super Fight IN Tokyo Dome*. It was an answer to the question asking if he would retire if he had lost the fight.

> 出る前に負けること考えるバカいるかよ!
> *deru mae ni makeru koto kangaeru baka iru kayo!*
> Does anyone think of losing before the match?

Reference:

- [アントニオ猪木 名言・格言 ｜ 出る前に負けること考える馬鹿いるかよ。](https://meigen.info/?p=1705) (Japanese)
- [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwSYR1FbtsI) showing the scene

---

The quote after his daydream was from the song [*Seishun Amigo*](https://www.project-imas.com/wiki/Seishun_Amigo) by [Shuuji to Akira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%ABji_to_Akira).

> Si si 俺たちはいつでも 二人で一つだった **地元じゃ負けしらず**
> *Si si ore-tachi wa itsudemo futari de hitotsu datta **jimoto ja makeshirazu***
> Si si, the two of us were always one, **at home we were invincible**, weren’t we?